# How do you record the second touch in UITouch

Tags: ios, swift, uitouch

I'm new to Swift, and I'm trying to make a chess game.

So I want the code to record the first touch's location, and then record a second touch's location, but I'm not sure how to get this second touch. I think there's a function, but I can't find it online. I'm doing this in `touchesEnded` method under `SKScene`.

Comment: Implementiong chess game UI is easy if you make the board with UIButtons/UIVIews. It ieasy to recognise the touch on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of an array of touch locations and append the locations to the array after each touch in your `touchesEnded` method. So your method could look like this:

```
func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard self.touchLocations.count < 2 else {
        return
    }

    if let myTouch = touches.first {
        self.touchLocations.append(myTouch.locationInWindow(myTouch.window))
    }
}
```

The first touch will come through and you append that first location, then the second touch should come through and you append that one as well. Just remember to clear the array once the turn is completed.

You can also achieve this with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and add it to your scene. You'll then just get the `locationInView` of the gesture that gets passed in to your selector and do the location appending like I mentioned above.